# Basic tensor derivation

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

Let $D$ be a tensor derivation on a mnaifold $M$. I have to show that if $D(\partial_i)=\sum F_i^j \partial_j$, then $D(dx^j)=-\sum F_i^j dx^i$.

Any help on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you show how far you got yourself? This helps others to provide better answers.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. 

Not far, I'm afraid. I've been playing around with the product rule, but it has not given me much. Also, the minus sign throws me off. I feel like there is something pretty trivial I'm missing. Forgive me, but I'm completely new to tensors.

Comment: @L.Henry, I have reverted your edit — which turned the question incomprehensible. **Please** do not do that.

Comment: If you find an answer satisfying, accept it. Not accepting any answers may repulse some people to bother with your questions.

Comment: BTW this is the first part of exercise 6 in Barrett O'Neill's book on semi-Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Here's a much simpler method: https://idontgetoutmuch.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/tensor-derivation/

Comment: @idontgetoutmuch You should write your compact proof as an answer, because I think people should have alternative more compact answer easily available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Let $D$ be a tensor derivation on a manifold $M$

I assume it means $D$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear and obeys Leibniz rules with respect to tensor multiplication and contraction [See axioms 2 and 3 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#Lie_derivative_of_tensor_fields). Actually here we only need 2 things:

(1) For every vector field $X$ and 1-form $\omega$ we have
$$D(\omega(X))=D(\omega)(X)+\omega(D(X)).$$
(2) For function $f$ and vector field $X$ we have
$$D(fX)=D(f)X +fD(X)$$
In order to show
$$D(dx^j)=-F_i^j dx^i$$
we have to prove that for every vecotr field $X$ the following holds:
$$\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)}=\color{blue}{-F_i^j dx^i(X)}.$$
So let $X$ be a vector field and $X=X^i\partial_i$ (denote it $\star$).

Ladies and Gentelmen! Let's compute
$$D(dx^j(X))\stackrel{(1)}{=}\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)}+dx^j(D(X))\stackrel{\star}{=}\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)}+dx^j(D(X^i\partial_i))\stackrel{(2)}{=}\\
\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)}+dx^j(D(X^i)\partial_i+X^iD(\partial_i))=\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)}+D(X^j)+X^idx^j(D(\partial_i))=\\
\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)}+D(X^j)+X^idx^j(F^k_i\partial_k)=\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)}+D(X^j)+X^iF^j_i $$
Compute the same again, but this time
$$D(dx^j(X))\stackrel{\star}{=}D(dx^j(X^i\partial_i))=D(X^idx^j(\partial_i))=D(X^j).$$
So if we extract $\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)},$ we get that
$$\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)}=\color{green}{-X^iF^j_i}$$
To complete the proof we just need to compute $\color{blue}{-F_i^j dx^i(X)}.$ So
$$\color{blue}{-F_i^j dx^i(X)}\stackrel{\star}{=}-F^j_i dx^i(X^k\partial_k)=\color{green}{-X^iF^j_i}.$$
As a result
$$\color{red}{D(dx^j)(X)}=\color{green}{-X^iF^j_i}=\color{blue}{-F_i^j dx^i(X)}.$$

Comment: Thanks alot!! That was more hairy than I thought. I see that there's a lot of notation in  this topic that I have to decipher, before I can solve problems like this help-free :)

Comment: @L.Henry Feel free to ask what bothers you

Comment: +1 Nicely done. May I point out a typo: you wrote "excract", where extract was meant.

Comment: @Hrodelbert Fixed, Thx

Comment: @FallenApart You say for instance that $X^i dx^j (\partial_i) = X^j$. Can you explain how you arive at this, because I have difficulty seeing it directly from the definitions?

Comment: @L.Henry There is summation in $i.$ BTW I used [Einstain notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) in my answer. So just for one element (without summation) $dx^j(\partial_i),$ we know that it equals
$$dx^j(\partial_i)=\delta_i^j.$$
Hence
$$X^idx^j(\partial_i)=X^i\delta_i^j.$$
So as we sum everything we get that
$$\sum_iX^idx^j(\partial_i)=\sum_iX^i\delta_i^j=X^j,$$
Which in Einstein notation (which I used in my answer) is
$$X^idx^j(\partial_i)=X^i\delta_i^j=X^j,$$

Comment: @FallenApart I see! Thanks alot!